# Find recurring events in time series with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series of events and I would like to count previous non-consecutive occurrences of each type of event in the time series. I want to do this with pandas. I could do it iterating through the items, but I wonder if there is a clever way of doing it w/o loops.

To make it clearer. Consider the following time series:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=4, freq='H')
data = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=dates,columns=["event"])

                    event
2011-01-01 00:00:00   a
2011-01-01 01:00:00   a
2011-01-01 02:00:00   b
2011-01-01 03:00:00   a
```

I would like to add a new column that tells, for each element in the "event" column, how many non-consecutive times that element has previously appeared. That is, something like this:

```
                    event #prev-occurr
2011-01-01 00:00:00   a        0
2011-01-01 01:00:00   a        0
2011-01-01 02:00:00   b        0
2011-01-01 03:00:00   a        1
```

Comment: Just to be clear I'm following you, what output would you want if the event column were `["a","a","b","a","a","b","a"]`?

Comment: @DSM In that case the output should be `["0","0","0","1","1","1","2"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't really have good `groupby` support for contiguous groups yet, but we can use the shift-compare-cumsum pattern and then a dense rank to get what you need, IIUC:

```
>>> egroup = (df["event"] != df["event"].shift()).cumsum()
>>> df["prev_occur"] = egroup.groupby(df["event"]).rank(method="dense") - 1
>>> df
                    event  prev_occur
2011-01-01 00:00:00     a           0
2011-01-01 01:00:00     a           0
2011-01-01 02:00:00     b           0
2011-01-01 03:00:00     a           1
2011-01-01 04:00:00     a           1
2011-01-01 05:00:00     b           1
2011-01-01 06:00:00     a           2
```

---

This works because we get a contiguous event group count:

```
>>> egroup
2011-01-01 00:00:00    1
2011-01-01 01:00:00    1
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2
2011-01-01 03:00:00    3
2011-01-01 04:00:00    3
2011-01-01 05:00:00    4
2011-01-01 06:00:00    5
Freq: H, Name: event, dtype: int64
```

and then we can group this by the event types, giving us the non-ranked version:

```
>>> for k,g in egroup.groupby(df["event"]):
...     print(g)
...     
2011-01-01 00:00:00    1
2011-01-01 01:00:00    1
2011-01-01 03:00:00    3
2011-01-01 04:00:00    3
2011-01-01 06:00:00    5
Name: event, dtype: int64
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2
2011-01-01 05:00:00    4
Name: event, dtype: int64
```

which we can finally do a dense rank on.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DSM! That is, as I requested, a really clever way of doing what I needed :-) 
I did not know that one can group in the way you did. If I understand it right, it is like concatenating the columns of `df` and `egroup`, group on the `event` column and then removing `df`columns. Right?